Geoserver ImageMosaic timeregex.properites not reading correctly
I’m trying to setup an ImageMosaic raster store to serve hourly rasters, following the instructions here: ImageMosaic
My rasters are titled like so, in a director called rasters/
qpe_20241004060000.tif
qpe_20241004070000.tif
qpe_20241004080000.tif

My timeregex.properites looks like
regex=([0-9]{14}),format=yyyyMMddHHmmss
My indexer.properties looks like:
TimeAttribute=ingestion
ElevationAttribute=elevation
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Integer
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)

however, when I try to create the store, my dbf file doesn’t seem read the timestamps correctly, it looks like:

so it doesn’t seem to picking up the timestamp.
I’ve tried a variety of other regex’s too and nothing seems to work.
What am i doing wrong?
Geoserver version 2.26.0 on Ubuntu

Per the very helpful Geoserver forums, here is the resolution?
https://discourse.osgeo.org/t/imagemosaic-timeregex-properites-not-reading-correctly/110680
In short:  Shapefiles don't support time values, so have to move to postGIS.
